# Why is it an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, char, infinite-loop, integer-overflow

I tried to write the 255 ascii character to the console, but i've got an infinite loop

```
for(char i=0; i<256; i++) {
    cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: change `char` to `int` and note the difference.

Comment: You are not saving anything by making `i` a `char`. Use the `int` type it is supposed to be the natural size for an integer on your architecture (and thus optimally efficient for this kind of loop).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `i` can never be greater or equal to `256`. It will overflow before it. Remember that it's type is `char` whose maximum value can be `255` if it is *unsigned*, otherwise `127` if it is *signed*.

Whether `char` is *unsigned* or *signed*, is implementation-defined. But usually, to my experience, it is signed, which means usually the maximum value `char` can attain is `127`.

So `i` increments from `0` to `127`, then becomes `-128` from which it increases upto `127`, and so on, well if it is *signed*. If it is *unsigned*, then it will go from `0` to `255`, then next it will become `0` (due to overflow), and the story starts again, and again!

Comment: for(unsigned char i=0; i<256; i++) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }

Comment: @HardRain: What is that? Even that is infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

Because *all* values of `char` are smaller than 256.

For the comparison, the `char` `i` is converted to `int`, resulting in a value between -128 and 127 usually (with signed two's complement 8-bit `char`s), or between 0 and 255 (inclusive) if `char` is an unsigned 8-bit type.

Once the maximal value a `char` can hold is reached, a further increment will lead to a wrap-around to 0 if `char` is unsigned, and to an implementation-defined conversion of the `int` value 128 that the increment produced to `char` when it is stored back, usually the result is -128, when `char` is signed.

Answer (score 3):

You should compile with warnings on (`-Wtautological-compare` for this issue).

In C++, each integral type has a range of possible values. This range is (normally) implementation defined, though on common platforms (x86) it is frequent to have:

- `signed char` in [-128, +127] (+)
- `short` in [-2**15, 2**15-1]
- `int` in [-2**31, 2**31-1]

If you try to increment a signed integral type beyond its maximum value, you enter the realm of **undefined behavior**. On common implementations, it wraps around (just like for unsigned types), so 127 + 1 becomes -128 (for a `char`).

When you compare with `256`, you first cast the value from `i` into an `int` (the type of `256` without integral suffixes) and then perform the comparison. However, since `i` is always in the [-128, 127] (+) range it is strictly inferior to `256` so the condition is always true.

*(+) It is implementation defined whether `char` is signed or not, if `char` is unsigned then its range is more likely [0, 255].*

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
 {
    cout << char(i) << " ";
 }
```